# How to optimize Django DateTimeField for null value lookups in postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, indexing, query-optimization

I have a problem with deeper undestanding of indexing and its positive side. Lets assume such model

```
class SupportTicket(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    closed_at = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
```

to keep it clean I do not add `is_closed` boolean field as it would be redundant (since `closed_at == None` implies that ticket is open). As you can imagine the open Tickets will be looked up and called more frequently and thats why I would like to optimize it database-wise. I am using postgres and my desired effect is to speed up this filter

```
active_tickets = SupportTicket.objects.filter(closed_at__isnull=True)
```

I know that postgres support DateTime indexing but I have no knowleadge nor experience with null/not null speed ups. My guess looks like this

```
class SupportTicket(models.Model):
    
    class Meta:
        indexes = [models.Index(
            name='ticket_open_condition',
            fields=['closed_at'],
            condition=Q(closed_at__isnull=True))
        ]

    content = models.TextField()
    closed_at = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
```

but I have no idea if it will speed up the query at all. The db will grow in about 200 Tickets a day and will be queried at around 10 000 a day. I know its not that much but UX (speed) really matters here. I will be grateful for any suggestions on how to improve this model definition.

Comment: `closed_at = models.DateTimeField(default=None, db_index=True)` likely will be sufficient. An index normally will reduce the lookup to *O(log n)* index lookup. Retrieving the records however can still take a long time since these can be "scattered" over the disk.

Comment: Take a look at here [Slow Query](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions) for how to troubleshoot/analyze queries. Test with some actual data. My suspicion is that populating the UI forms/reports will take a good deal longer then the database end of it.